# merge two different calculations grouping by author

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to show total commits, average code volume, average work load, most productive day and most productive time of each author.

For such case, I calculated commits, code volume and work load related part in such way

## commit frequency, code volume and code work load

```
after = pd.to_datetime("2020-12-28", utc=True)
before = pd.to_datetime("2021-04-10", utc=True)
df = self.df[(self.df["date"] > after) & (self.df["date"] < before)]
# commit frequency, avg commit size, most productive day, most productive hour
grouped = df.groupby(by=['author']).agg({
    'sha': 'size',
    'code_volume': 'mean',
    'code_work_load': 'mean'
})
grouped
```

## result

```
sha code_volume code_work_load
author          
N thapa 1   2.000000    2.000000
Sujan Bista 1   -14.000000  44.000000
Nilesh Adhikari 1340    6.344030    29.151493
```

While for most productive day and time, I did in the below way

## Most productive time

```
after = pd.to_datetime("2020-12-28", utc=True)
before = pd.to_datetime("2021-04-10", utc=True)
df = self.df[(self.df["date"] > after) & (self.df["date"] < before)]
commit_df = df.loc[:]
commit_df['sha'].nunique()
commit_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.strftime("%I:%M  %p")

grouped = commit_df.groupby(by=['time'], as_index=False)['sha'].nunique().sort_values(by='time', ascending=False)
max_count = grouped['sha'].max()
most_productive_time = grouped.loc[grouped['sha'] == max_count, ['time']]
most_productive_time
```

## result

```
    time
129 03:25 PM
104 02:58 PM
36  01:46 PM
```

## Most productive day

```
after = pd.to_datetime("2020-12-28", utc=True)
before = pd.to_datetime("2021-04-10", utc=True)
df = self.df[(self.df["date"] > after) & (self.df["date"] < before)]
commit_df = df.loc[:]
commit_df['time'] = commit_df.date.dt.weekday
grouped = commit_df.groupby(by=['time'], as_index=False)['sha'].nunique().sort_values(by='time', ascending=False)
max_count = grouped['sha'].max()
most_productive_day = grouped.loc[grouped['sha'] == max_count, ['time']]
most_productive_day
```

## result

```
time
3   3
```

I want the result as follow

```
    sha code_volume code_work_load most_productive_day most_productive_time
author          
N thapa 1   2.000000    2.000000        3               12:10 PM
Sujan Bista 1   -14.000000  44.000000   1               1 PM
Nilesh Adhikari 1340    6.344030    29.151493  0        07:30 AM
```

Comment: you could try merging the grouped results using `pd.merge` on a unique `key` which is present in all three grouped dataframes, or take look into `transform` function that acts upon `pandas.Series` but you can transform individual columns.

Comment: Thank you @Priya. But how can I bind most productive day and time to particular author in the first result where author is listed?

Comment: The `commit_df` is same for all the three cases. So did you try doing `reset_index` and maybe `pd.concat` on `axis=1` (works only when the num rows are equal) and just see what you are getting.

Comment: so to concat first I have to calculate most productive day and time by grouping with author(as of now they are not grouped as per author) and then only concatenate?

Comment: It is little hard to say without data sample. Grouping by author leads to a grouped dataframe where author is the index. When you perform `reset_index` on a grouped dataframe, the previous index will be just repeated through out the column...looks similar to the result generated by `partition by` in sql. Then check whether the rows are equal in all the three dataframes and then concat and see what you get. It gives you some insight.